# Auth failed when run tests against Liberty Arquillian Remote

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

OpenLiberty 20.0.0.1
AdoptOpenJDK 8

Here is the [sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter).

The *arquillian.xml* config.

```xml
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="liberty-remote">
        <configuration>
            <property name="hostName">localhost</property>
            <property name="serverName">defaultServer</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
            <property name="password">admin</property>
            <property name="httpPort">9080</property>
            <property name="httpsPort">9443</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

The *server.xml* used for the OpenLiberty server.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- This template enables security. To get the full use of all the capabilities, a keystore and user registry are required. -->

    <!-- For the keystore, default keys are generated and stored in a keystore. To provide the keystore password, generate an 
         encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it below in the password attribute of the keyStore element. 
         Then uncomment the keyStore element. -->
    <!--
    <keyStore password=""/> 
    -->
    <!-- userName and password should also be set in arquillian.xml to these values -->
    <quickStartSecurity userName="admin" userPassword="admin" />

    <!-- Enable the keystore -->
    <!-- Start/restart the server, there are two files being created, keys.jks and ltpa.keys
    in the folder <OpenLiberty server>/usr/servers/test/resources/security -->
    <!-- Check the certificate:
    keytool -list -v -keystore key.jks-->
    <!-- Export the cert:
    keytool -export -alias default -file testwlp.crt -keystore key.jks -->
    <!-- Import into JDK:
    keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias testwlp -import -file testwlp.crt -->
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="password" />

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" />

    <!-- This section is needed to allow upload of files to the dropins directory, the remote container adapter relies on this configuration -->
    <remoteFileAccess>
        <writeDir>${server.config.dir}/dropins</writeDir>
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For example, configure a basic user registry using the
        basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name attribute of the user element. For the password, 
        generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it in the password attribute of the user element. 
        Then uncomment the user element. -->
<!--    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"> -->
<!--         <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  -->
<!--    </basicRegistry>-->

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

I put this server.xml into *wlp/usr/servers/defalutServer/* and start the OpenLiberty Server by `wlp/bin/server start defaultServer`.

Then I exported the cert from the jks file generated by OpenLiberty and imported it into my local JDK certs.

When I ran the following command to run tests.

```
mvn clean verify -Parq-liberty-remote
```

It was failed, the following error was shown in the console.

```sh
[INFO] Running com.example.it.GreetingResourceTest
Feb 19, 2020 3:40:53 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.remote.WLPRemoteContainer setup
FINER: ENTRY
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feb 19, 2020 3:40:54 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.remote.WLPRemoteContainer setup
FINER: RETURN
Feb 19, 2020 3:40:54 PM io.openliberty.arquillian.remote.WLPRestClient isServerUp
FINER: ENTRY
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.795 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.it.GreetingResourceTest
[ERROR] com.example.it.GreetingResourceTest  Time elapsed: 2.771 s  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not determine remote server status : Could not successfully connect to REST endpoint, server returned response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [X-Powered-By: Servlet/4.0, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="IBMJMXConnectorREST", Content-Language: en-US, Content-Length: 0, Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 07:40:55 GMT] [Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Could not successfully connect to REST endpoint, server returned response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [X-Powered-By: Servlet/4.0, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="IBMJMXConnectorREST", Content-Language: en-US, Content-Length: 0, Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 07:40:55 GMT] [Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}
```

Comment: Is is possible to disable the SSL connection when administrating the OpenLiberty server?